# how to work on a project that solely consists of .class files in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, class, project

it's been a while since i've been working with java and especially with eclipse. My professor sent me a huge folder with many subfolders and subsubfolders, that mainly contain .class java files. Now I'm supposed to work on these files, but i just can't seem to figure out how to get all of them working. I found a few solutions for single class files, but i have a whole folder hirarchy here that i want to work on.

I hope you can help me - I read something about decompiling? How does that work?

Note that I have around 50 different files here that need to be accessible.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you should simply talk to your professor and ask him why he didn't send you the sources.

Comment: you can use inteliji as your IDE it converts class file automatically to .java files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a java decompiler like JD-GUI, you can find it at http://jd.benow.ca/ . This is a very handy tool to have when you want to view a decompiled version of your jar. There are plugins available for eclipse and intellij as well.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the class you are attending is not something like "CS 902 - Reverse Engineering", because if that was the case, you would know what to do with the .class files.

So, one of the following holds true:

1. Your professor has made a mistake, and instead of sending you the java files, he/she sent you the class files instead.
2. Your professor sent you the entire project, which contains both .java and .class files, and for some reason you have only managed to find the .class files, while the .java files are there, and you just haven't found them.  Unfortunately, the convention in the java world is to store .class files in a subfolder under the project root, so if you copy the project folder, you are copying .class files together with everything else.
3. Your assignment is to write new code which makes use of classes and interfaces supplied by your professor, but your professor does not want you to have the source code of those files.  In this case, you can still work with the .class files, because the public definitions contained therein are parseable by Eclipse and usable in your project, ***without any reverse engineering***.  So, what you need to do is to find a way to tell eclipse that these .class files form a "Class Library" which is supposed to be used by your project, and then go ahead and develop new .java files making use of the library. I don't remember how this is done in Eclipse, but you should be able to find it out by yourself, or look it up, or perhaps someone else might post a how-to answer.  However, at this point we do not even know whether this is in fact what you need to do.